# Android: EACCES Permission denied to save a file in the ringtones folder

Tags: java, android, stream, permission-denied, ringtone

I`m trying to download an MP3 file from the web using a stream and save it to the ringtones folder using this method

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES)
```

I`ve added the required permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.write_external_storage"/>
```

When I check my app on an emulator (I currently use Andy) the app works perfectly.
When I check it on an actual device (more than one) I get no permission:
/storage/sdcard0/Ringtones/MyRingtone.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Anyone has any idea what is missing?

Here is the full method to download:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground.Started");

    int count;
    try {
        mDownloadSuccess = true;
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100%
        // progress bar
        int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                8192);

        // Output stream
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES);
        File file = new File(path, mModel.getTitle() + ".mp3");

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        mDownloadSuccess = false;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
It appears that the uses-permission is case sensitive

It should have been:

I have no idea why it managed to save it on the emulator.